# How to print each function call during execution in WinDbg?

Tags: c++, debugging, windbg, stack-trace

I am debugging an application written in VC++.
How do i make WinDbg print the function name and all the values of the arguments to the functions during execution of the debuged process?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, i just found out that it can be done using the ["wt"](http://blogs.msdn.com/debuggingtoolbox/archive/2009/10/12/special-command-tracing-applications-using-wt.aspx) command.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for not giving a complete answer, but you might be able to join the dots with the suggestions I give.

First, [here's](http://blogs.msdn.com/ntdebugging/archive/2008/06/06/windbg-tip-kn-frame-dv-and-dt-it-s-so-easy.aspx) and article to describe how to get the values of variable in WinDbg - you might be able to use this to get the parameter values.

Also, this [blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/debuggingtoolbox/archive/2007/03/18/windbg-script-digging-the-call-stack.aspx) has quite a number of WinDbg script example, this could help you write a script to do task you need.

Hope this helps.